# Swift syntax mystery involving .with pattern

Tags: swift

Trying to analyze the syntax of following Swift code snippet. I am not concerned with the larger semantics, but if you want more context you can look [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/a43882db29c1591b207c25cb5846211cf30f0c19/docs/basic-tutorial.md). I am particularly interested in the use of `.with` which is some pattern I am not familiar with. Can anyone parse this and break it down for me?

```
  for (message, latitude, longitude) in noteContent {
    let note: Routeguide_RouteNote = .with {
      $0.message = message
      $0.location = .with {
        $0.latitude = Int32(latitude)
        $0.longitude = Int32(longitude)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where does that code come from? It won't compile out of the blue, so show us the context needed to make it compile.

Comment: It's not a mystery: first result in search for "Routeguide_RouteNote" on github brings this:  https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/a43882db29c1591b207c25cb5846211cf30f0c19/docs/basic-tutorial.md So read the docs...

Comment: This is Swift syntax question. There should be enough information in the code for a Swift programmer familiar with this pattern to parse it mentally. Don't sweat the semantics -- the docs will not help you there.

Comment: @wcochran, I see - you're asking about Swift syntax. This code includes a [trailing closure syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) - that's the `{ ... }` after `with`, and `$0` is a [shorthand argument name](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID100).

Comment: @wcochran also the dot in the beginning indicates that this is a static function and the type is inferred. This `let note: Routeguide_RouteNote = .with { ... }` is exactly like this `let note = Routeguide_RouteNote.with { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase `let note: Routeguide_RouteNote` tells Swift that what is on the far side of the upcoming equals sign will be a `Routeguide_RouteNote`.

This type conforms to `SwiftProtobuf.Message`.

Thus it has a static method called `with` that returns `Self`, i.e. in this case, a `Routeguide_RouteNote` instance.

Thus, thanks to the declared type, we can call that method by saying `.with` instead of saying `Routeguide_RouteNote.with`.

> **NOTE** This is due to a highly specialized rule in Swift that if a static/class func `MyType.myFunc` returns a MyType instance, then if the compiler already knows that this *is* a MyType, you can omit `MyType` when you call the func, i.e. you can call `.myFunc()` instead of `MyType.myFunc()`.
>
> It's exactly the same rule that allows you to set a view `backgroundColor` to `.red` instead of having to say `UIColor.red`. The compiler knows this will be a UIColor, so, looking at the rule more generally, any UIColor static/class member that yields a UIColor can be used without saying `UIColor` explicitly.

The `.with` function takes a function parameter which is expressed as an anonymous function in trailing closure syntax, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you @matt. That is exactly what I needed to understand.

Comment: I presume the second `.with` works exactly the same way, except now there is no need to declare any type because the compiler knows what a `location` is, even though I don't.

Comment: What is confusing to me -- are the anonymous functions called or merely defined?

Comment: @wcochran That is actually irrelevant. What I mean is: That depends on what the `.with` method _does_, so it is not a syntactic matter. You pass a function as an argument in a method call, but what that method does with it is what that method does with it. _It_ might call it, now or later, or it might just store it for use in a completely different way. The syntax says nothing about that. But _you_ are not calling it; you are defining-and-passing it, to be used at the pleasure of `.with`. Does that help?

Comment: That does help -- thanks! I won't ask about the for-loop syntax :)

Comment: You mean the three things in parentheses? It's just multiple assignment by way of a tuple.